# Table of Contents that Straddles Multiple Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: hyperlink, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tableofcontents

I have some huge Jupyter notebooks, each with lots of HTML links between sections, and some have gotten so big that they run really slowly now, but I'm reluctant to break them up because I find the links and cross-references very useful.

Is there any way to create a TOC (table of contents) that references multiple Jupyter notebooks?

That would allow me to keep smaller notebooks while retaining links between the sections.

Answer (score 2):

Just reference the notebook name (using a relative path if needed) with the bookmark in the linked notebook.

`[My content's text](notebook2.ipynb#bookmark)`

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks! I don't suppose there is some way to stop Jupyter from opening new instances of Notebook 2 every single time you click on the link, is there?

In other words, the behavior I want is this:
* I click on a link
* Jupyter opens the notebook coded in the link
* Some time later, I click on it again
* Jupyter uses the previously opened instance rather than opening a second instance.

Comment: I don't know.  Just click the tab instead or maybe ask another question.

Comment: Clicking the tab does not give me a robust TOC, because the links don't just open the notebook; they also jump to specific places in the notebook. If you have LaTex markup (with MathJax), for instance, these notebooks take a long time to load. Might be o.k. to take a hit when you open a notebook for the first time, but the TOC is unusable if you have to reinitialize the notebook every single time you jump to some part of it.

Comment: Here's a design suggestion for a [multi-window Jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/design/issues/18) . Maybe that's what's needed to implement a decent multi-notebook TOC. I assume this is just a twinkle in someone's eye at this point and has not been implemented:

[multi-window Jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/design/issues/18)

Comment: @JohnStrong I tried fast unique tab from this answer and it works for me in Chrome on win 7. https://superuser.com/a/1057347